# What are you supposed to use to write in Latex? There doesn't seem to be any application akin to Word or Google Docs

Tags: overleaf

I am new to Latex (technically not "new" - I got my interest from the Maths Stack Exchange, where I absorbed some Latex typesetting skills for maths). Hopefully, this type of question is allowed on this SE: basically, where do I start? I initially thought Latex was primarily for scientific typesetting for maths and chemistry etc only. ie recursive fractions, square roots, chemical equations which are impossible to typeset without using the "\blahblah" command.

But I really like the aesthetic and simplicity of Latex documents which I have seen in thesis and papers. I am actually very confused as to how this whole thing works - but hopefully there is a guide somewhere? I thought that there would be an app to make Latex documents like you do in Word but it seems that there are *so many* different downloads and extensions you have to get. Additionally, it seems very complex and overkill to write stuff like \startdocument, put an "&" sign whenever you want a new sentence, and especially tables get very complex when Word does it instantly.

Is it designed for everyday use? I am a school student but it would be nice to do homework in Latex (it seems only formal documents are in Latex, however). I have a mac and am just using the online Overleaf, but why are there so many more online website to do the same thing? (sorry I am not sure what tag to use)

Comment: You are right. There are many editors you can choose from. You can use basically anything that exports unformatted text.

Comment: I'd recommend TexStudio, but its a personal preference.

Comment: You might also like to skim the lessons at https://www.learnlatex.org/

Comment: I've written a mini guide to getting started with LaTeX on the Mac which you might find helpful: https://amunn.github.io/latex/nano-companion.pdf

Comment: If you want a more Word-like experience but with the power of LaTeX, you might want to try [LyX](https://www.lyx.org).

Comment: And although you mention editors, I think your question would be better answered by looking at [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/2693) and the https://learnlatex.org site mentioned by David.